# Which are the best services to receive verification SMS (multiple accounts)

Tags: web-services, mobile, phone, sms, data-verification

I'm am looking forward to a service where I can receive multiple verification SMS to my browser (no physical number), each one with a unique number.

Currently I'm using https://simtonet.com/ and it costs 4$/month approx per number.

I want to try other options for a similar price if possible. I have found many expensive ones. This is a list of other potential options https://www.digitalinformationworld.com/2018/05/apps-for-phone-verification.html

Is any company you recommend for a similar task, with a similar price/quality of service?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/sms) in the past.  They are simple to use and quite feature intensive!  The price ([link](https://www.twilio.com/sms/pricing/us)) is $0.0075 USD per message and the cost to get a number is only $1 a month.